# How to get a coordinate of a pivot point of an object with bpy?

Tags: python, origin

How to get a coodinate of an object's pivot point with bpy? (python)

Comment: This depends on what you mean by the pivot point. If you mean an origin, then that's just the object's `location`. If it's parented to something and you want its location in the world space, then use `matrix_world.translation`.